# Use parameter with a Struts2 Jquery parameter

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2

```
            <sj:submit
                openDialog="editDialog" 
                value="Modifica" 
                button="true"
                onClickTopics="setIdComFamOnEditForm"
             />
```

I have a seto of submit button. Every submit button is not linked to a form, but act as a simple button. Whene i press the button, I need to fire setIdComFamOnEditForm. How can i set a parameter for the topic??

Comment: What is setIdComFamOnEditForm?

Comment: Is a javascript funciont

Answer (score 0):

For javascript functions, you want to use the `onclick` attribute, not `onClickTopics`.  You can call a javascript on click with parameters as you normally would.  Example:

```
onclick="alert('Insert your message here')"
```